# How to set delta delta.logRetentionDuration localy?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I can easily set this option on databricks, but how to do the same with the local pyspark and delta.spark library

I've tried to set this option in sparkConf, but it doesn't work

```
 ("spark.databricks.delta.logRetentionDuration", "interval 52 weeks")
```

Comment: How are you confirming it doesn't work? This config is respected and should work.

Comment: I've resolved this problem, and the solution was to use spark.databricks.delta.properties.defaults.logRetentionDuration instead spark.databricks.delta.logRetentionDuration